# Why is documentFragment no faster than repeated DOM access?

Tags: javascript, performance, dom

I was always under the impression that rather than touching the DOM repeatedly, for performance reasons, we should use a `documentFragment` to append multiple elements to, and then append the fragment into the document once, rather than just repeatedly appending new elements one-by-one into the DOM.

I've been trying to use Chrome's dev tools to profile these two approaches, using this test page:

```
<button id="addRows">Add rows</button>
<table id="myTable"></table>
```

Test 1 uses this code to append 50000 new rows to the table:

```
let addRows = document.getElementById('addRows');
addRows.addEventListener('click', function () {
    for (let x = 0; x < 50000; x += 1) {
        let table = document.getElementById('myTable'),
            row = document.createElement('tr'),
            cell = document.createElement('td'),
            cell1 = cell.cloneNode(),
            cell2 = cell.cloneNode(),
            cell3 = cell.cloneNode();

        cell1.textContent = 'A';
        cell2.textContent = 'B';
        cell3.textContent = 'C';

        row.appendChild(cell1);
        row.appendChild(cell2);
        row.appendChild(cell3);
        table.appendChild(row);
    }
});
```

Clicking the button while recording in Chrome's Timeline tool results in the following output:

[image: Repeated DOM interaction]

Test 2 uses this code instead:

```
let addRows = document.getElementById('addRows');
addRows.addEventListener('click', function () {
    let table = document.getElementById('myTable'),
        cell = document.createElement('td'),
        docFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

    for (let x = 0; x < 50000; x += 1) {
        let row = document.createElement('tr'),
            cell1 = cell.cloneNode(),
            cell2 = cell.cloneNode(),
            cell3 = cell.cloneNode();

        cell1.textContent = 'A';
        cell2.textContent = 'B';
        cell3.textContent = 'C';

        row.appendChild(cell1);
        row.appendChild(cell2);
        row.appendChild(cell3);

        docFragment.appendChild(row);
    }

    table.appendChild(docFragment);
});
```

This has a performance profile like this:

[image]

The second, supposedly much faster alternative to the first, actually takes longer to run! I've run these tests numerous times and sometimes the second approach is slightly faster, and sometimes, as these images show, the second approach is slightly slower, but not once has there been any significant difference between the two approaches.

What is happening here? Are browsers optimized so well now that this makes no difference anymore? Am I using the profiling tools incorrectly?

I'm on Windows 10, with Chrome 57.0.2987.133

Comment: Good point... I couldn't find much difference too (check [here](https://repl.it/HJom) and [here](https://repl.it/HJoo))... I have even tried to append the doc frag to the table through a `window.requestAnimationFrame()` but there is no big difference. I guess Chrome renderer is getting optimized in time.

Comment: I'm guessing right now that it's in-browser optimization. Using Firefox, the difference between the two iterations of the code is much more marked

Comment: Well.. in fact since you don't alter any CSS properties but instead just insert plain new nodes, the rendering engine is not forcing a reflow as it would when fiddling with existing nodes' properties. So we see no difference. However if you check my answer you will immediately notice the dramatic difference that fall into place if the forced reflow is eliminated.

Comment: If you want to test the performance difference between different approaches, you should only change as less as possible. In Test 1 `table = document.getElementById('myTable')`  and `cell = document.createElement('td')` in the for loop, in Test 2 those are outside of the loop.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well actually your test code just insert nodes and do not alter their content or CSS which would in fact force the rendering engine to a reflow.

I have prepared 3 tests to demonstrate this dramatic difference.

1. Simple DOM modificiation resulting Layout Trashing
2. Simple DOM modificiation through `window.requestAnimationFrame()`
3. Virtual DOM modification through `document.createDocumentFragment()`

**Notes:**

- You might like to test on full screen.
- In Firefox I have obtained even more dramatic results.

```js
// Resets the divs
function resetLayout() {
  divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
  speed.textContent = "Resetting Layout...";
  setTimeout(function() {
               each.call(divs, function(div) {
                                 div.style.height = '';
                                 div.offsetTop;
                               });
               speed.textContent = "";
             }, 16);
}
// print the result
function renderSpeed(ms) {
  speed.textContent = ms + 'ms';
}

var divs        = document.querySelectorAll('div'),
    raf         = window.requestAnimationFrame,
    each        = Array.prototype.forEach,
    isAfterVdom = false,
    start       = 0;

// Reset the Layout

reset.onclick = resetLayout;

// Direct DOM Access

direct.onclick = function() {
                   isAfterVdom && (divs = document.querySelectorAll('div'), isAfterVdom = false);
                   start = performance.now();

                   each.call(divs, function(div) {
                   var width = div.clientWidth;
                   div.style.height = ~~(Math.random()*2*width+6) + 'px';
                   div.style.backgroundColor = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
                 });

                   // Render result
                   renderSpeed(performance.now() - start);
                 };

// Access DOM at the next frame by requestAnimationFrame

rAF.onclick = function() {
                isAfterVdom && (divs = document.querySelectorAll('div'), isAfterVdom = false);
                start = performance.now();

                each.call(divs, function(div) {
                                  var width = div.clientWidth;
                                  // Schedule the write operation to be run in the next frame.
                                  raf(function() {
                                        div.style.height = ~~(Math.random()*2*width+6) + 'px';
                                        div.style.backgroundColor = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
                                      });
                                });
               // Render result
               raf(function() {
                     renderSpeed(performance.now() - start);
                   });
             };

// Update the vDOM and access DOM just once by rAF

vdom.onclick = function() {
                 var sectCl = divCompartment.cloneNode(true),
                     divsCl = sectCl.querySelectorAll('div'),
                     dFrag  = document.createDocumentFragment(),
                     width  = divCompartment.querySelector('div').clientWidth;
                 
                 isAfterVdom = true;
                 end = 0;
                 start  = performance.now();
                 each.call(divsCl, function(div) {
                                     div.style.height = ~~(Math.random()*2*width+6) + 'px';
                                     div.style.backgroundColor = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
                                   });
                 dFrag.appendChild(sectCl);
                 divCompartment.parentNode.replaceChild(dFrag, divCompartment);
                 // Render result
                 renderSpeed(performance.now() - start);
               };
```

```css
html {
  font: 14px Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  //word-break: break-word;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
}

button {
  background-color: white;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5%;
  margin: 3px;
  background: white;
  border: solid 2px white;
  border-radius: 10px
}

section {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#speed {
  font-size: 2.4em;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Updating 1000 DOM Nodes</h1>
  <section>
    <button id="reset">Reset Layout</button>
    <button id="direct">Update Directly</button>
    <button id="rAF">Update by rAF</button>
    <button id="vdom">Update by vDOM</button>
    <section id="speed"></section>
    <section id="divCompartment">
      <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
    </section>
</body>
```

Comment: That's actually a really interesting experiment, and the comparison between `requestAnimationFrame` and the `documentFragment` approach is highly illuminating - I'm surprised actually that `documentFragment` beats `requestAnimationFrame` (at least in Chrome). Thanks for providing this information :)

Comment: @danwellman.. Thank you.. but in the meantime i have stretched my tests further.. and you know what..? The results are very interesting... I will update this answer with some further data in a few hours. This time it will update 1000 items 50 times repeatdetly... and lets see who is the fastest.

Comment: I'm looking forward to seeing these results also :)

Comment: @danwellman.. I had to insert another answer due to the length. Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 11):

Sorry... Due to the 30000 character limit in the answers and the length of the previous one i have to place another one as an extension to my previous answer.

I guess everybody's heard that direct DOM access is no good... Yes that's what i had always been told and so believed in the correctness of the virtual DOM approach. Though i hadn't quite understood the fact that while both the DOM and vDOM are represented on the memory, how come one is faster than the other? Actually streching my test further i have come to believe that the real bottle neck boils down to the JS engine performance if you update the DOM properly.

Now lets imagine the case of having 1000 divs to be updated repeatedly on background-color and height CSS properties.

If you do this directly on DOM elements all you have to do is to keep a nodeList of these elements and simply alter their `style.backgroundColor` and `style.heigth` properties.

If you do this by a document fragment you have the apparent benefit of not touching the DOM multiple times, instead first you have to

1. clone the parent container of the 1000 `div` elements.
2. access the nodeList containing the divs like `parent.children`
3. perform necessary alterations on each `div` element,
4. create a document fragment
5. re-clone the previously cloned (step 1) parent container element and append it to a document fragment (or alternatively you may chose to clone the divs' container from the DOM if you need the fresh ones but this way or that way for each modification you have to clone them)
6. append the document fragment to the parent of div container in the DOM and remove the old div container. Basically a `Node.replaceChild` operation.

In fact for this test we don't need a document fragment since we are not creating new nodes but just updating the already existing ones. So we can skip the step 4 and at step 5 we can directly use the cloned copy of our divs container as a source to our replaceChild operation.

How to update DOM properly..? Definitely asynchronously. So as for the previous example if you move the direct update portion to an asynchronous timeline like `setTimeout(_ => renderDirect(),0)` it will be the fastest among all. But then repeatedly updating the dome can be a little tricky.

One way to achieve this is to repedeatly feed a `setTimeout(_ => renderDirect(),0)` with our DOM updates like.

```
for (var i = 0; i < cnt; i++) setTimeout(_ => renderDirect(divs,width),0);
```

In the above case the performance of the JS engine is very material on the results. If our code is too light, than multiple cycles will stack up on a single DOM update and we will observe only a few of them. In this particular case, we got to see only like 9 of the 50 updates.

[image]

So delaying each turn further might be a good idea. So how about;

```
for (var i = 0; i < cnt; i++) setTimeout(_ => renderDirect(divs,width),i*17);
```

[image]

Well this is much better, I've got 22 of the 50 updates actually painted on my screen. So it happens to be, if the delay is chosen to be long enough you'll have all the frames painted. But how much long is a problem. Since if it's too long you have idle time for your rendering engine and it resembles slow DOM update. So for this particular test, it turns out to be something like 29-30ms ish... is the optimal value to observe 50 separate DOM updates of all 1000 divs in 1400 ms. Well at least on my desktop with Chrome. You may observe something entirely different depending on the hardware or the browser.

[image]

So the `setTimeout` resolution doesn't look very promising to me. We have to automate this job. Lucky us, we have the right tool for this job. rAF to help again. I have come up with a helper function to abuse the rAF (requestAnimationFrame). We will update the 1000 divs all at once, in one go, by directly accessing the DOM at the next available animation frame. And... while we are still in the asynchronous timeline we will request another animation frame from within the currently executing callback. So another rAF is called from the callback of the rAF recursively. I named this function `looper`

```
var looper = n => n && raf(_ => (renderDirect(divs, width),looper(--n)));
```

well it's a bit of an ES6 code. So let me translate it into classing JS.

```
function looper(n){
  if (n !== 0) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){
                                   renderDirect(divs,width);
                                   looper(n-1);
                                 });
  }
}
```

Now everything should be automated.. It seems pretty cool and done in 1385ms.

[image]

So since now we are a little more knowledgeable we may play with the code.

```js
// Resets the divs
function resetLayout() {
  divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
  speed.textContent = "Resetting Layout...";
  setTimeout(function() {
               each.call(divs, function(div) {
                                 div.style.height = '';
                                 div.backcgoundColor = '';
                               });
               speed.textContent = "";
             }, 16);
}
// print the result
function renderSpeed(ms) {
  speed.textContent = ms + 'ms';
}

function renderDirect(divs,width){
  each.call(divs, function(div) {
                    div.style.height = ~~(Math.random()*2*width+6) + 'px';
                    div.style.backgroundColor = '#' + Math.random().toString(16).substr(-6);
                  });

  // Render result
  renderSpeed(performance.now() - start);
}

function renderByVDOM(sct,prt,wdt){
  var //dFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
      divs  = sct.children;
  each.call(divs, function(div) {
                    div.style.height = ~~(Math.random()*2*wdt+6) + 'px';
                    div.style.backgroundColor = '#' + Math.random().toString(16).substr(-6);
                  });
  //dFrag.appendChild(sct);
  prt.replaceChild(sct, divCompartment);
  // Render result
  renderSpeed(performance.now() - start);
}

var divs        = document.querySelectorAll('div'),
    width       = divs[1].clientWidth;
    raf         = window.requestAnimationFrame,
    each        = Array.prototype.forEach,
    isAfterVdom = false,
    start       = 0,
    cnt         = 50;

// Reset the Layout

reset.onclick = resetLayout;

// Direct DOM Access

direct.onclick = function() {
                   var looper = n => n && raf(_ => (renderDirect(divs, width),looper(--n)));
                   isAfterVdom && (divs = document.querySelectorAll('div'), isAfterVdom = false);
                   start = performance.now();
                   //for (var i = 0; i < cnt; i++) setTimeout(_ => renderDirect(divs,width),i*29);
                   looper(cnt);
                 };

// Update the vDOM and access DOM just once by rAF

vdom.onclick = function() {
                 var sectCl = divCompartment.cloneNode(true),
                     parent = divCompartment.parentNode,
                     looper = n => n && raf(_ => (renderByVDOM(sectCl.cloneNode(true), parent, width),looper(--n)));
                 
                 isAfterVdom = true;
                 start  = performance.now();
                 looper(cnt);
               };
```

```css
html {
  font: 14px Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
}

button {
  background-color: white;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5%;
  margin: 3px;
  background: white;
  border: solid 2px white;
  border-radius: 10px
}

section {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#speed {
  font-size: 2.4em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="index.js" async></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>Updating 1000 DOM Nodes</h1>
  <section>
    <button id="reset">Reset Layout</button>
    <button id="direct">Update Directly</button>
    <button id="vdom">Update by vDOM</button>
    <section id="speed"></section>
    <section id="divCompartment">
      <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
    </section>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

So the tests look like direct access through `rAF` is better than cloning and working on the clone and replacing the old one with it. Particularly when a huge DOM chunk is replaced it seems to me that the GC (Garbage Collect) task gets involved in the middle of the job and things get a little sticky. I am not sure how it can be eliminated. Your ideas are most welcome.

**A Side Note:**
This test also shows that the current (Version 91.0.838.3) of the new chromium based Edge Browser is performing DOM renderings ~15% faster than the current (Version 89.0.4389.114) Chrome.

Comment: Thanks again for this detailed examination of browser behavior with regard to the performance of different approaches, I can see you've spent a lot of time and effort on this, and it is appreciated :)

Comment: @danwellman You are most welcome. It was also interesting for me to find out direct DOM access is not evil and provided that all updates are correctly done through a helper function which utilizes rAF, you should be just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how exactly to interpret your profiler results but running it through benchmark.js test shows second option is faster in Chrome: https://jsbench.me/awj1gwhk9i/1

ALso faster in FF (although a bit less difference)

Comment: When I run the jsbench test, the second version is only marginally faster, just 3% or so. Is that expected?

Comment: for me, it was 50% faster. Maybe you could start Chrome with --enable-benchmarking flag to improve accuracy. It's not 100% accurate test but it is the best one out there. For me, case 2 was consistently faster. That said, it's really hard to tell how much faster performance is expected on each configuration.

Comment: that's the kind of improvement I was expecting! Adding the flag didn't work for me?

Comment: I've run it maybe 10 times. Results are from 10 to 50% faster. In average I'd say about 20-25%

Comment: `case 2` is 5% more slower if we move query selector and row creation in `case 1` to the outside of the loop

Answer (score 1):

How about this lifehack (the last button, named "Hide/Show") - https://jsfiddle.net/qnxfhtyL/ ?

It's based on the above demos and seems like the simplest and the fastest of them all - at least for this particular test.

The trick is to just hide the html block (divCompartment.style.display = 'none'), then have it processed as required, and then just show it back again (divCompartment.style.display = 'block'). The browser won't have to redraw it 1000 times while it's hidden. Hiding and showing remains unnoticed. Here's the whole code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html spellcheck="false">
<head>
</head>
<style>
    html {
    font: 14px Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    }

    * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }

    h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    //word-break: break-word;
    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    }

    button {
    background-color: white;
    }

    div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 5%;
    margin: 3px;
    background: white;
    border: solid 2px white;
    border-radius: 10px
    }

    section {
    overflow: hidden;
    }

    #speed {
    font-size: 2.4em;
    }
</style>
<body>
<h1>Updating 1000 DOM Nodes</h1>
<section>
    <button id="reset">Reset Layout</button>
    <button id="direct">Update Directly</button>
    <button id="rAF">Update by rAF</button>
    <button id="vdom">Update by vDOM</button>
    <button id="hide_show">Update by Hide/Show</button>
    <section id="speed"></section>
    <section id="divCompartment">
        <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
    </section>

<script>
    // Resets the divs
    function resetLayout() {
      divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
      speed.textContent = "Resetting Layout...";
      setTimeout(function() {
                   each.call(divs, function(div) {
                                     div.style.height = '';
                                     div.offsetTop;
                                   });
                   speed.textContent = "";
                 }, 16);
    }
    // print the result
    function renderSpeed(ms) {
      speed.textContent = ms + 'ms';
    }
    
    var divs        = document.querySelectorAll('div'),
        raf         = window.requestAnimationFrame,
        each        = Array.prototype.forEach,
        isAfterVdom = false,
        start       = 0;
    
    // Reset the Layout
    
    reset.onclick = resetLayout;
    
    // Direct DOM Access
    
    direct.onclick = function() {
                       isAfterVdom && (divs = document.querySelectorAll('div'), isAfterVdom = false);
                       start = performance.now();
    
                       each.call(divs, function(div) {
                       var width = div.clientWidth;
                       div.style.height = ~~(Math.random()*2*width+6) + 'px';
                       div.style.backgroundColor = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
                     });
    
                       // Render result
                       renderSpeed(performance.now() - start);
                     };
    
    // Access DOM at the next frame by requestAnimationFrame
    
    rAF.onclick = function() {
                    isAfterVdom && (divs = document.querySelectorAll('div'), isAfterVdom = false);
                    start = performance.now();
    
                    each.call(divs, function(div) {
                                      var width = div.clientWidth;
                                      // Schedule the write operation to be run in the next frame.
                                      raf(function() {
                                            div.style.height = ~~(Math.random()*2*width+6) + 'px';
                                            div.style.backgroundColor = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
                                          });
                                    });
                   // Render result
                   raf(function() {
                         renderSpeed(performance.now() - start);
                       });
                 };
    
    // Update the vDOM and access DOM just once by rAF
    
    vdom.onclick = function() {
                     var sectCl = divCompartment.cloneNode(true),
                         divsCl = sectCl.querySelectorAll('div'),
                         dFrag  = document.createDocumentFragment(),
                         width  = divCompartment.querySelector('div').clientWidth;
                     
                     isAfterVdom = true;
                     end = 0;
                     start  = performance.now();
                     each.call(divsCl, function(div) {
                                         div.style.height = ~~(Math.random()*2*width+6) + 'px';
                                         div.style.backgroundColor = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
                                       });
                     dFrag.appendChild(sectCl);
                     divCompartment.parentNode.replaceChild(dFrag, divCompartment);
                     // Render result
                     renderSpeed(performance.now() - start);
                   };

    // Hide -> Update -> Show

    hide_show.onclick = function() {
                        isAfterVdom && (divs = document.querySelectorAll('div'), isAfterVdom = false);
                        start = performance.now();
                        width  = divCompartment.querySelector('div').clientWidth;

                        divCompartment.style.display = 'none';
                        each.call(divs, function(div) {
                            div.style.height = ~~(Math.random()*2*width+6) + 'px';
                            div.style.backgroundColor = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
                        });
                        divCompartment.style.display = 'block';

                        // Render result
                        renderSpeed(performance.now() - start);
                    };
    </script>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```