# Set height with Javascript is slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, performance, reflow

I have two html tables that contains all kind of elements (span, input, select,...) and I want to force the rows of those tables to have the same height. Unfortunately, setting the attribute 'height' on `tr` or `td`doesn't work (the row is higher if it contains at least one element that exceed the given height).

I have not found a way how I can force row height with css, so I have written a Javascript function that loop over all the rows, check the height of the row of the left table with the height of the corresponding row in the right table and if they are different I set the height (changing the style) to the  biggest value.

It works... but it is very very slow if the tables have a lot of rows! I think this is due to the fact that each change to the style cause a reflow.

Any hint? Note that I cannot merge the two tables.

Here my code snipped, but maybe I need a total different approach...

```
var rightTableRows = mainTable.children("tbody").children("tr:parent");
var leftTableRows = colHeader.children("tbody").children("tr:parent");

for (chr=0;chr < leftTableRows .length;chr++) {
    var rowLeft = leftTableRows [chr];
    var heightleft = rowLeft.offsetHeight;
    var rowRight = rightTableRows[chr];
    var heightright = rowRight.offsetHeight;
    if(heightleft != heightright){
            console.log("left: "+heightleft +" - right: "+heightright);
        if(heightleft>heightright){
           rowRight.setAttribute("style","height:"+heightleft+"px");
        }else{
           rowLeft.setAttribute("style","height:"+heightright+"px");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are repeatedly reading then writing to the DOM. This is considered a big no-no for performance. The proper way is to do all of your 'reads' and then all of your 'writes' - otherwise you are forcing reflows/calculations in-between. You'd actually be better off with two loops, one that finds the correct heights and then a second that applies them:

```
var rightTableRows = mainTable.children("tbody").children("tr:parent");
var leftTableRows = colHeader.children("tbody").children("tr:parent");
var length = leftTableRows.length;
var heights = [];

for (var chr = 0; chr < length; chr++) {
    var rowLeft = leftTableRows[chr];
    var heightleft = rowLeft.offsetHeight;
    var rowRight = rightTableRows[chr];
    var heightright = rowRight.offsetHeight;

    if (heightleft > heightright) {
        heights.push({
            elem: rowRight,
            height: heightleft
        });
    } else {
        heights.push({
            elem: rowLeft,
            height: heightright
        });
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < heights.length; i++) {
    heights[i].elem.style.height = heights[i].height + 'px';
}
```

Now the elements and their new height get stored as objects in an array, then you just iterate over the array. You never read from the DOM again after the first loop. Other optimizations include removal of the unneeded `if()` statement, caching the length of the HTML nodelist, and specifically writing `style.height` rather than `setAttribute()` (slower).

Comment: Cool, thx. I try it right away. In my opinion the if should improve performance: I set the height only if it is different.

Comment: Performance is MUCH better! :-) It doesn't work on IE, I check it and I'll come back here...

Comment: Cool, let me know if there are any errors reported in IE (and which version) and we can try to work through them

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work so well in IE. The workaround I have found is: i) set height of left AND right row. ii) add 1 pixel to the height.

Comment: Which version of IE are you testing?

Comment: IE 11, but the same effect happen on Edge

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the max height of the cells. You should probably transform your tables into divs and use [display flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex).

This will allow you to have the behavior you want but will imply that you change the construction of the HTML code.

Instead of having the elements of the first table and the second, you will have to alternate one then the other.

Comment: I have taken this into consideration. It is an expending task but i think I have to do in this way in the next future. For the moment I need a quick (temporary) solution ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take an excerpt from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37040384/1203738) by jfriend00. by sure to upvote their answer.

**DOM Modifications**

1. **Reflows are queued.**  ....
2. **Requesting certain properties can trigger an immediate reflow.** There are exceptions to the above rule that you want to make sure you avoid.  For example if you request certain DOM properties that require proper layout for the property value to be accurately reported and there is a pending layout from a prior modification, then the browser may relayout the document synchronously before returning the property you requested.  These type of properties usually involve things like screen position and other properties that would obviously be affected by the layout of the document.  There are many articles on this topic if you want to find further details.  In many cases your code won't be using these properties anyway, but if so, the usual workaround is to request all the needed properties first before making any changes to the DOM.
3. **Batch up all your DOM changes at once.**  The worst thing to do is to make a DOM change, wait a few ms with a timer, make another DOM change, wait a few ms with a timer and so on because you will have DOM change, reflow, repaint, DOM change, reflow, repaint, etc...  Instead, make sure you're doing all pending DOM changes at once in one synchronous piece of Javascript.  This will then allow the browser to queue the reflow and repaint and do it only once after you've made all your DOM changes.  If you want to get even smarter about the batching, you will collapse modifications to the same element so that it is only processed once with the final value.  So, if elementA was first given a new value of 3 and then later in the same batch was given a value of 4, when processing the batch of data, you want to skip the 3 and just process the 4.
4. **DOM modifications can sometimes be optimized.**  ....

---

Point 2 and 3 are very relevant, you're getting the offsetHeight for each row and then setting a new value.
So the changes aren't batched. Each change will cause a reflow because you're getting an offsetheight on the next iteration for the following row.

To optimize, read all rows and save all pending changes in memory. 
Then apply the new row heights in a new loop. Where you pull the new values from memory.

Comment: Oh. Cool. With your suggestion the total time decreased from 40s to 400ms (speedup of 100x!)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the cause of this but:

Setting line-height style to td should increase the height of the td that will increase the height of the tr. 
if not you can set encapsulate the content of the td in a div and then set line-height on that.

Another option, to speed things up, is to set the same style class to all elements.
Then after calculation of the height set the line-height for the class. This will change the height of all the elements that uses this class.
Read about Javascript's styleSheet object to understand how this can be done....