# Does browser optimize continuous batch dom update natively?

Tags: javascript, dom, browser

I write a test for continuous batch dom update in the code below:

```js
    const container = document.querySelector('#container');
    const button = document.querySelector('button');


    function fulfill(text) {
      container.innerHTML = '';
      for (let i = 0; i < 10000 * 3; i++) {
        const label = document.createElement('div');
        label.innerHTML = text;
        container.appendChild(label);
      }
    }

    button.onclick = function () {
      fulfill("Hello");
      fulfill("World");
    }
```

```html
  <button>Click</button>
  <div id="container"></div>
```

If the `fulfill` function execute sequentially twice, the page should show `Hello` first, and then show `World`. But it seems only show `World` eventually

So I guess the browser seems optmize continuous batch dom update natively? But I can't find any documents or references about it. Which keywords should use to google it?

Comment: There is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714942/how-to-stop-intense-javascript-loop-from-freezing-the-browser for preventing browser freeze.

Comment: And  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37039667/executing-multiple-dom-updates-with-javascript-efficiently says that reflows are queued.

Comment: Heavy synchronous code blocks the browser - repainting only occurs after the event loop is free.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the browser only repaints when no other tasks (e.g. JS) are executing on the event loop.

The browser also attempts to delay costly re-calculation of layout/style until the repaint, but a script can force it by asking for updated information about position and computed style of elements after modifying the DOM, which can cause performance issues.

The relevant keywords for searching are:

- Layout/reflow and repaint/rendering ([How Browsers Work: Behind the scenes of modern web browsers](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/#The_main_flow) is a comprehensive overview, and [Rendering: repaint, reflow/relayout, restyle](https://www.phpied.com/rendering-repaint-reflowrelayout-restyle/) is focused on reflow/repaint and the associated performance pitfalls)
- [The Event Loop and Run-to-completion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#Run-to-completion)

The detailed specification of the event loop and the place of the rendering step in the processing model is [here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#update-the-rendering). (The full spec's intended audience are browser vendors, so it's quite hard to follow for the uninitiated; there's a [web developer edition](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/), but it [omits the detailed description of the event loop](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/webappapis.html#event-loops)).